# PHP walk through flat array to create json string

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm using an older version of Cake ( 1.3 ).

I have an array which returns the structure of a directory, I have then flattened the array using Set::Flatten() and it outputs the following example;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Screen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm-1.png
    [projects.raiders.0] => Webserver_requests_graph.jpg
    [images.0] => Screen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm.png
    [triggers.0] => Screen_Shot_2017-10-09_at_4_52_32_pm.png
    [providers.0] => testScreen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm.png
)
```

The 'key' represents the file structure, so 0 is /, projects is a directory, the raider is a subdirectory of projects and so on....

I need to create a JSON string which walks through each layer of the above array and put it into the following format;

```
[ ['fullpathname', 'displaytext', 'isfile'] ]
```

I also need to add dots to represent the original directory structure, so the above array will turn into the following JSON string;

```
[
    ['/', '/', 'false'],
    ['/Screen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm-1.png', 'Screen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm-1.png', 'true'],
    ['/projects', '.. projects', 'false'],
    ['/projects/raiders', '.. .. raiders', 'false'],
    ['/projects/raiders/Webserver_requests_graph.jpg', '.. .. .. Webserver_requests_graph.jpg', 'true'],
    ['/images', '.. images', 'false'],
    ['/images/Screen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm.png', '.. .. Screen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm.png', 'true'],
    ['/triggers', '.. triggers', 'false'],
    ['/triggers/Screen_Shot_2017-10-09_at_4_52_32_pm.png', '.. .. Screen_Shot_2017-10-09_at_4_52_32_pm.png', 'true'],
    ['/providers', '.. providers', 'false'],
    ['/providers/testScreen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm.png', '.. .. testScreen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm.png', true]
]
```

I was wondering if I could get some guidance, I'm really really stuck on how to go about this. I have heard about array_walk_recursive, but I dont understand it. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: WHAT'S THIS `.. .. .. Webserver_requests_graph.jpg` Isn't it invalid. I think it need to be `../../../Webserver_requests_graph.jpg`  and so on for others

Comment: Have a look at the format i've described ... that is the 'Display Text' what is output to the user

Comment: Why is your input `5` items and the output `11`, or am I missing something.

Comment: The 'key' represents the file structure ... So it needs to display each directory instance, hence the 11 outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
<?php

$final_array = [['/', '/', 'false']]; // i have taken first value from output by-default because i am unable to create any logic for first value through the given input

foreach($array as $key=>$val){
    if($key=='0'){
        $final_array[] = ['/'.$val,$val,'true'];
    }else{
        $exploded_key = explode('.',$key);
        foreach ($exploded_key as $k=>$v){
            if($v =='0'){
                $dots = '.. ';
                for ($i=0;$i<count(array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k));$i++){
                    $dots .= '.. ';
                }
                $final_array[] = [ '/'. join('/', array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k)).'/'.$val,$dots.$val,'true'];
            }else{
                $dots = '.. ';
                for ($i=0;$i<count(array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k));$i++){
                    $dots .= '.. ';
                }
                $final_array[] = [ '/'. join('/', array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k+1)),$dots.$v,'false'];
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/890536

***Note:- if you want json as output then use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) like below:-***

```
echo json_encode($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/890584

Comment: Thats just turning it back into an array, it needs to be turned into a JSON string similar to the output that is at the bottom of my question

Comment: use `json_encode()` to get json output. Check this:- https://eval.in/890584

Comment: Oh yes, thats exactly it ... I thank you so much, your help with this is greatly greatly appreciated!!

Comment: @BigJobbies  glad to help you :):)